# How do I require a file in Java?

Tags: java, c++, require

How do I require a file in Java? Much like require(); in PHP, and #include in C++.
Would I use #include as in C++ or is there another function?

I'm not looking for *import*.

Comment: Do you mean importing another file with `import`?

Comment: Have you cracked a Java book? Ever? It's on page 1 usually...

Comment: Yes, would this work in java?

Comment: Yes, I read the oracle docs xD

Comment: Would Import work with a file, or just a project?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the `import` keyword. For example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

Comment: Could I include a file, rather than a project?

Comment: You can **only** `import` classes (which are more or less equal to files). Importing projects is not called importing. You have to add them to the classpath.

Comment: I'm not looking for import, as I already said xD

Comment: I'm afraid you *are* looking for `import`, but you simply didn't get it yet :)